# django-smsmigration error django 1.8

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7, xampp, django-1.8

I'm quite new to django and i have a question, following the instruction [here](https://code.google.com/p/django-sms/)
i'm getting an error in mysql that says:

django.db.utils.programmingError(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'uuid NULL, 'status' varchar(16) NOT NULL, 'status_message' varchar(128) NULL, 'b' at line 1")

should i add the models manually if so where can i find the models?

and from what i have read, there is a bug on '*django.db.backends.mysql*' and if that is the case how can i go around it?